# Proving that a polynomial over $K[t]$ has a multiple zero if and only if $f$ shares a factor with $f'$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, derivatives, polynomials, field-theory

The author is trying to prove that a polynomial $f$ has a repeated zero in it's splitting field over $K$ if and only if $f$ shares a common factor with $f'$ of degree $≥1$.

He first proves that if $f$ has a repeated zero, then $f$ and $f'$ have a common factor of degree $≥1$ in $K[t]$, in the following way:

$$f=(t-a)^2g$$
$$f'=(t-a)^2g'+2(t-a)g$$

At the end of the proof he states "$f$ and $f'$ share a common factor in $S[t]$, so they share a common factor in $K[t]$". Where $S$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $K$.

I understand how these polynomials share a common factor in $S[t]$, but how is it that the author infeere from this that they share a common factor in $K[t]$?

---

He then continues to prove that if $f$ has no repeated roots, then it doesn't share a common factor with $f'$. This part of the proof is understandable since it doesn't depend on $K[t]$.

---

I would really appreciate any help/thoughts.

Comment: Isn't it $f = (t-a)^2g$?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for noticing. I edited the question

Comment: $f$ is irreducible so it cannot have any roots in K[t]. Unless K[t] refers to some other extension.

Comment: I'm with Crenner on this one.  Something's fishy! 

Comment: I mixed up two theorems, dear god. Both Crenner and Lewis are right, the statement is not about irreducibles but rather about polynomials in general. Thank you. I edited again

Comment: If you don't want this question because of [your later one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2557205), delete it (use a browser on a computer if you cannot find the delete button). Please don't vandalize it, as it is confusing to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be the splitting field for $f \in K[t]$.

($\longrightarrow$)
Since $f$ has a repeated zero, $\gcd(f,f') \ne 1$ in this case as you show, the degree of $\gcd(f,f')$ is greater or equal to 1.

($\longleftarrow$)
The other direction is that suppose $\gcd(f,f') = g(t)$, then zeros of $g$ are also zeros of $f$ as well. 
Thus those zeros are in $S$.

Note that even though $f \in K[t]$, it is not necessarily that all zeros are in $K$. For example, $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ are in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ but zeros are in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I apologize for practically changing the question, but is this proof compatible with the new edits mentioned in the comments of the above ?