# Proving that a polynomial $f$ over $K$ has a repeated zero in its splitting field if and only if $f$ shares a common factor with $f'$ in $K[t]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, derivatives, polynomials, field-theory, splitting-field

Theorem: a polynomial $f$ over $K$ has a repeated zero in its splitting field if and only if $f$ shares a common factor with $f'$ in $K[t]$.

The author starts by proving that if $f$ has a repeated zero, then $f$ and $f'$ share a common factor of degree $≥1$ in $K[t]$, in the following way:

$$f=(t-a)^2g$$
$$f'=(t-a)^2g'+2(t-a)g$$
$$=(t-a)[(t-a)g'+2g]$$

He follows to claim that "since $f$ and $f'$ share a common factor in $\Sigma[t]$, they must share a common factor in $K[t]$", where $\Sigma$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $K$.

I understand how, from the fact that $f$ has a repeated zero in its splitting field, $f$ and $f'$ must share a factor in $\Sigma[t]$, but how does the author infer from this that they must then share a factor in $K[t]$?

---

The second part of the proof, in which the author proves that if $f$ has no repeated zeroes then it doesn't share a common factor with $f'$, is understandable since it doesn't depend on $K[t]$.

---

I would really appreciate any help/thoughts.

Comment: That is because it also means $\gcd(f,f')$ has degree $\ge1$ and the Euclidean algorithm for the g.c.d. takes place in $K[t$].

Comment: OK, let me just see if I understand it correctly. By the division algorithm (over  $∑$), $f=f'q+r$, (degree of $r$ $<$ degree of $f'$) where all these polynomials are in $∑[t]$. There is only one choice for $q$ and $r$. But since the division algorithm can also be used over $K[t]$, there must exist polynomials $a$ and $b$ over $K$ such that $f=f'a+b$, (degree of $b$ $<$ degree of $f'$). By the author's proof, $r=0$, and if we are to claim that $a≠q$ then that would would mean that there is another polynomial over $∑$ that would suffice the division algorithm, which is a false statement.

Comment: Because of uniqueness, quotient and remainder are the same in $K[t]$ and $\Sigma[t]$, hence the g.c.d. is the same.

Comment: @Bernard. Wait. Could you please explain in more detail how this implies that they share a factor in $K[t]$?

Comment: @Leo The two polynomial have a root in common in $\Sigma[t]$, so their greatest common divisor has degree $\ge1$.

Comment: @egreg. Yeah, that part I understand, but how does that proves that they share a common factor on $K[t]$?

Comment: That's because if they share a common root in the splltting field, all its conjugate roots (i.e. the roots of its minimal polynomial, which is a factor of $f$) are shared.

Comment: Does this means that given the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $K$, call it $m$, both $f$ and $Df$ share all it's zeroes?? If so, again, how would this prove that they share a common factor in $K[t]$?

Comment: @Leo The gcd is the same in $K[t]$ and in $\Sigma [t]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference to the splitting field could be misleading. Suppose there is an extension field $F$ where $f$ has a multiple root $a$.

The argument in your question proves that $f$ and $f'$ have a common root. In particular, their greatest common divisor $p$ in $F[t]$ has degree $>0$.

Now the key fact is that, since both polynomials belong to $K[t]$, their gcd is computed with the Euclidean algorithm that takes place in $K[t]$. If you think to compute it in $F[t]$, you would do exactly the same operations; hence the gcd is the same in $F[t]$ as in $K[t]$.

This proves that $p\in K[t]$ and, since it has positive degree, it is the required *nonconstant* common factor.

Comment: Is the greatest common divisor $(t-a)$?

Comment: @TheCodingWombat Not necessarily. Take $f(t)=t^3$, for instance.

Comment: Okay, but the questioner proved that $f$ and $f'$ have a common divisor $p$ in $F[t]$ of degree >0.

What does this have to do with the greatest common divisor of $K[t]$? I understand that a gcd in $K[t]$ is also a gcd in $F[t]$, but why is it the other way around?

Comment: @TheCodingWombat Because the Euclidean algorithm performed in $F[t]$ only uses elements in $K$.